# Implement ABAC with AccessControl NPM package?

Tags: node.js, permissions, access-control, role-based-access-control

I've seen `accesscontrol` recommended for node RBAC, and the documentation *says* that it is kind of a merge of both [rbac](/questions/tagged/rbac) and [abac](/questions/tagged/abac).

What I'm seeing instead is that everything is still limited 100% to roles, the only "attribute"-type permissions are based on the attributes of the resource, not the user.

In a perfect world, I'd have user attributes like `dateJoined` or `publishedCount` or something like that, which `accesscontrol` would look at for whether the user has (usually edit) access to such and such resource.

Am I out of luck with `accesscontrol`? If I am, is there another package that would support what I'm trying to do? If not, I'll have to look into building it from scratch, I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked into [node-abac](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-abac)? Old but possibly ok. Otherwise, there's no reason you need to limit yourself to Node.js. You can take a XACML engine (e.g. AuthZForce) or Open Policy Agent (Rego) and connect your environment to that. You'll get full ABAC either way.

Comment: I appreciate the info! This is a small, personal project that likely won't *actually* see any outside users, but I wanted to have something in place just in case. I'll try the node-abac package, as the other options seem a little above my pay grade.